Does anyone know any preferably free Quran translations that even kids can understand well? Ones that cover the full Quran please!
I'm an autistic teen and really struggle with the metaphors and complex/older translations. I've been using the Quran.com translation with the notes in parenthesis, but it still is too complex and metaphorical for my mind.
I'm looking for mainly kids things cause they tend to be more clear and direct which is how my brain understands. Also there's the bonus of kids things tend to be more fun and engaging which really helps me in learning too.
